# Why the Dropdown button dont pops out?

Tags: asp.net, razor, bootstrap-5

I have problem that I can't solve on my own, so I'm asking for help.

I want to build website project of movies with on Asp.net Mvc project with Movies, Actors and Producers, i just put a dropdown button but the dropdown button is not working and i dont know why.

Im learning to use Asp .net

this is my _Layout.cshtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - MoviePage</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/MoviePage.styles.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.11.3/font/bootstrap-icons.min.css">

</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <a class="navbar-brand" asp-controller="Movies" asp-action="Index">MoviePage</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex justify-content-between">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Movies" asp-action="Index"><i class="bi bi-film"></i> Movies</a>
                 

                        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                <i class="badge-info bi-gear"></i> Management
                            </a>

                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" asp-controller="Cinemas" asp-action="Index"><i class="bi bi-camera-reels"></i> Cinemas</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" asp-controller="Producers" asp-action="Index"><i class="bi bi-headset"></i> Producers</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" asp-controller="Actors" asp-action="Index"><i class="bi bi-person-square"></i> Actors</a>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>

                    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Filter" style="padding-right: 25px;">
                        <input name="searchString" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for a movie..." aria-label="Recipient's username" aria-describedby="button-addon2">
                        <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit"><i class="bi bi-search"></i></button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
            @RenderBody()
        </main>
    </div>

    <footer class="border-top footer text-muted">
        <div class="container">
            &copy; 2024 - MoviePage
        </div>
    </footer>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    @await RenderSectionAsync("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

Solve the error of the dropdown button

Comment: I solved the error installing Boostrap and the Popper.js on the NuGet Package Manager

Answer (score 0):

try adding the below cdns

```js
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

```css
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```